# Url loading the login page again after login in Laravel4

Tags: laravel-4.2

I have this link

http://ideconnect.com/rescom_summit_bangalore_2016/login

When I try to Login

```
id:meaaow@gmail.com
pass:123456
```

it redirects me to the main page . Can any one let me know whats the problem

**My Routes**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to execute when that URI is requested.
|
*/

// Route::get('/', function()
// {
//  return View::make('hello');
// });

Route::get('logout',function(){
    Session::flush();
    Auth::logout();
    return Redirect::to('login');
});

Route::get('admin/logout',function(){
    Session::flush();
    Auth::logout();
    return Redirect::to('admin/login');
});

Route::get('fileupload',function(){
    return View::make('fileinclude');
});

Route::post('fileupload','FiletestController@indx');

Route::get('admin/emergencyUse','AdminController@emergencyUse');
Route::get('admin/emergencyUse12','AdminController@emergencyUse12');

Route::get('admin/listusers/(:any)/(:any)', function($event,$userid){
    return Controller::call('AdminController@singleuser',array('event'=>$event,'userid'=>$userid));
});
Route::controller('admin','AdminController');
Route::controller('sales','SalesController');

Route::controller('event1/rankingform','RankingformController');
Route::controller('event2/rankingform','RankingformController');
Route::controller('rescom_summit_bangalore_2016/rankingform','RankingformController');
Route::controller('hotelier_summit_mumbai_2016/rankingform','RankingformController');
Route::controller('hotelier_summit_africa_2016/rankingform','RankingformController');
Route::controller('design_mission_saudi_arabia_2016/rankingform','RankingformController');
Route::controller('design_mission_north_east_2016/rankingform','RankingformController');
Route::controller('design_mission_south_west_2016/rankingform','RankingformController');
Route::controller('design_mission_middle_east_2016/rankingform','RankingformController');
Route::controller('design_mission_south_africa_2016/rankingform','RankingformController');
Route::controller('design_mission_turkey_2016/rankingform','RankingformController');
Route::controller('design_mission_asia_2016/rankingform','RankingformController');
Route::controller('design_mission_russia_2016/rankingform','RankingformController');
Route::controller('healthscape_series_2016/rankingform','RankingformController');

Route::controller('event1/form','FormController');
Route::controller('event2/form','FormController');

Route::controller('rescom_summit_bangalore_2016/form','FormController');
Route::controller('hotelier_summit_mumbai_2016/form','FormController');
Route::controller('hotelier_summit_africa_2016/form','FormController');
Route::controller('design_mission_saudi_arabia_2016/form','FormController');
Route::controller('design_mission_north_east_2016/form','FormController');
Route::controller('design_mission_south_west_2016/form','FormController');
Route::controller('design_mission_middle_east_2016/form','FormController');
Route::controller('design_mission_south_africa_2016/form','FormController');
Route::controller('design_mission_turkey_2016/form','FormController');
Route::controller('design_mission_asia_2016/form','FormController');
Route::controller('design_mission_russia_2016/form','FormController');
Route::controller('healthscape_series_2016/form','FormController');

Route::controller('rescom_summit_bangalore_2016/login','LoginController');
Route::controller('hotelier_summit_mumbai_2016/login','LoginController');
Route::controller('hotelier_summit_africa_2016/login','LoginController');
Route::controller('design_mission_saudi_arabia_2016/login','LoginController');
Route::controller('design_mission_north_east_2016/login','LoginController');
Route::controller('design_mission_south_west_2016/login','LoginController');
Route::controller('design_mission_middle_east_2016/login','LoginController');
Route::controller('design_mission_south_africa_2016/login','LoginController');
Route::controller('design_mission_turkey_2016/login','LoginController');
Route::controller('design_mission_asia_2016/login','LoginController');
Route::controller('design_mission_russia_2016/login','LoginController');
Route::controller('healthscape_series_2016/login','LoginController');




Route::get('login',function(){
    return View::make('mainLogin');
});



Route::controller('hotelbookingform','HotelbookingformController');
Route::controller('hotelbooking','HotelbookingController');

Route::get('/',function(){
    return Redirect::to('/login');
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Post the `routes.php` file please :)

Comment: @Matt also In my localhost this is not happening , Do you think its related with config file ??